# How do I convert a number enum column to tinyint?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

Developing in Laravel 5.7, using a MySQL database. On a couple of my database columns I have the type of enum - didn't do my research and made the enum full of numbers (0-2, or 0-3). After reading the pros and cons, I want to move away from enums and convert them to tinyints.

What's the best way to change the type of the column in my table to tinyint and convert the strings '0','1','2','3' to tinyint?

I don't really want to lose my data in the process.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#modifying-columns has information about modifying columns, however it does not support enums:

Only the following column types can be "changed": bigInteger, binary, boolean, date, dateTime, dateTimeTz, decimal, integer, json, longText, mediumText, smallInteger, string, text, time, unsignedBigInteger, unsignedInteger and unsignedSmallInteger.

Answer (score 4):

To be on a safe side I'd do this using temporary column;

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN _temp_col CHAR(1) COLLATE 'latin1_general_ci'; -- CHAR(1) is OK if you only have numeric ENUMs
UPDATE tbl SET _temp_col = col; -- ENUM values would be copied as is
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY COLUMN col TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED;
UPDATE tbl SET col = _temp_col; -- Values would be auto-converted to ints
ALTER TABLE tbl DROP COLUMN _temp_col;
```

Answer (score -1):

Experimenting with MySQL-8.0 generated the following conversion.

The `ALTER TABLE` seems to convert `'x'` -> `x+1`. So I guess that be altered per the subsequent `UPDATE` below

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version() |
> | :-------- |
> | 8.0.13    |
> ```

> ```
> create table x (y enum ('0','1','2','3') );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into x values ('1'),('0'),('2'),('3')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from x
> ```
>
> ```
> | y  |
> | :- |
> | 1  |
> | 0  |
> | 2  |
> | 3  |
> ```

> ```
> alter table x modify y tinyint unsigned;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from x;
> ```
>
> ```
> |  y |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> |  1 |
> |  3 |
> |  4 |
> ```

> ```
> update x set y=y-1
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from x
> ```
>
> ```
> |  y |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  0 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3cb83bdc1af72e3022f9865d3c079438)*

Comment: note this really isn't converting the value of the enum, just transforming the ordinal value in the list to the int. So `enum ('10','11','12','13') ` would convert to `(1,2,3,4)`, like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2a55c8cd8e17a9792fb1d3bea2123aaa)

Comment: Yup, the alter convert enum value to its index. So your trick with decrementing only works because of your order values in ENUM. If original ENUM was ('3', '2', '1', '0') it would be different story.

Comment: Your answer can be a source of confusion. It's not as easy as `set y = y - 1` because if you had an `enum('3', '2', '1', '0')` you would notice that the conversion doesn't simply add 1 to every value